# awk replace serialized number lines and move up other lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that has the following format

```
1 - descrio #944
name
address
2 - desanother #916 
name
address
3 - somedes #957 
name
address
```

and i want to get the output as,

```
Usercode #944, name, address
Usercode #916, name, address
Usercode #957, name, address
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`

```
awk 'NR%3 == 1{sub(/^.*#/, "Usercode #")};{ORS=NR%3?", ":"\n"};1' file
Usercode #944, name, address
Usercode #916, name, address
Usercode #957, name, address
```

For a variable number of rows

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/\n$/, "");
gsub(/\n/, ", "); printf "%s", $0""RT}END{print ""}' file
```

Comment: Some golfing `awk 'NR%3==1 {$0="Usercode "$NF} {ORS=NR%3?", ":RS}1'`

Comment: Thanks 1-CR. It worked fine. However I had to adjust the NR value since some files had 4 or 5 lines instead of 3 lines for the next record. May be if RS is set to be lines beginning with Usercode then I dont have to play with NR values since some files have a combination of 3, 4, or 5 lines for NR. How can I do the change?.

Comment: @user3616577, see the edited version. Mind the new version only works with GNU awk

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `#` in any of your descriptions, try:

```
sed -e 's/.*#/Usercode #/;N;N;s/\n/, /g' input
```

Comment: Thanks all of you. 1-CR's answer worked fine. However I had to adjust the NR value since some files had 4 or 5 lines instead of 3 lines for the next record. May be if RS is set to be lines beginning with Usercode then I dont have to play with NR values since some files have a combination of 3, 4, or 5 lines for NR.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this command also,

```
$ paste -d'~' - - - < ccc | sed 's/^[^#]*/Usercode /g;s/~/, /g'
Usercode #944, name, address
Usercode #916, name, address
Usercode #957, name, address
```

Comment: OP needs `,` followed by space as separator, not `,` by itself

Comment: ah but that's going to add a space to `,`s within name and address too, right

Comment: comma would be replaced by comma and a space.

Comment: well that's upto the OP but I don't believe he asked for commas in name and address to be tinkered with

Comment: i assumed there is no ~ character in his name or address.